# Переход к части из оглавление через ссылку в меню

Tags: vue.js

Есть страница с оглавлением. Слева оглавление(тип миеню), справа рендериться контент.
Было организовано через " keep-alive " . Если @клик по item из оглавления, отображается то что нужно(keep-alive is MyComponent).
Работает отлично.

Но эти же item из оглавления есть в главном меню, которое находиться в header-е.
Как можно организовать клик/переход, когда сделан @клик в Главном меню, что бы перекинуло на страницу с оглавлением, с таким контентом, что равно оглавлению?)

Answer (score 0):

Решение.

Главное меню (header).

```
<template>
<ul class="item-menu">
    <li @click="commonPerehod(mainTasks)"><a href="">main tasks</a></li>
    <li @click="commonPerehod(structure)"><a href="">structure</a></li>
    <li @click="commonPerehod(strategy)"><a href="">strategy</a></li>
    <li @click="commonPerehod(naming)"><a href="">naming</a> </li>
</ul>
</template>

data() {
  return {
    naming:'vName',
    strategy: 'vStrategia',
    structure:'vStructura',
    mainTasks:'vMainTask'
  }
}
methods: {
    commonPerehod(tasks){
        this.$router.push({name:'about',query:{'option':tasks}})
    }
},
```

Далее страничка About с оглавлением и 'keep-alive'

Оглавление:

```
<ul class="list_side_bar">
    <li @click="activePageAbout = 'vMainTask'" :class="{activeLi: activePageAbout == 'vMainTask'}">Main Task</li>
    <li @click="activePageAbout = 'vStructura'" :class="{activeLi: activePageAbout == 'vStructura'}">Structura</li>
    <li @click="activePageAbout = 'vStrategia'" :class="{activeLi: activePageAbout == 'vStrategia'}">Strategia</li>
    <li @click="activePageAbout = 'vName'" :class="{activeLi: activePageAbout == 'vName'}">vName</li>
                    
</ul>

<keep-alive>
     <component :is='activePageAbout'></component>
</keep-alive>

data() {
    return {
        activePageAbout:'vMainTask'
    }
},
mounted() {
    this.activePageAboutCPD = this.$route.query.option
}
```

На странице About, в оглавлении меняеться компонент. И теперь при переходе з главного меню, открывается About с выбраним компонентом.